# Show that $F(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin(x^{-6/5}) &x\ne 0\\ 0 &x=0 \end{cases}$ is absolutely continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I wanted to prove this statement. I know how to show that $F(x)=x^2\sin(1/x) (x\ne 0)$ and $F(0)=0$ is AC on [-1,1]. But I want to generalize it to $x^2\sin(x^{-p})$ where $p\in(1,2)$.

I tried to show that $F'$ is in $L^1([-1,1])$ which worked out. But to conclude that it is AC, I need $$F(x)=F(-1)+\int_{-1}^x F'(t)dt$$ which I'm struggling to prove.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is $x^{-5/4}$ for $x <0$?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said $\sin(1/x^{-p})$ @BrianMoehring

Comment: That doesn't help.  There's no problem defining $x^n$ for an integer $n$ and $x\neq 0$.  This isn't the case when the exponent isn't an integer.  What do you mean by your function when $x<0$?

Comment: Ok, I see. Functions that i'm interested in are of the form $x^2\sin(x^{-p})$ ($p\in(1,2)$). I might have mixed up my notation somewhere. I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: As best I can tell, maybe you're actually wanting $$F(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x)x^2\sin(|x|^{-p}).$$  Or maybe you're dealing with a complex exponential.  In any case, your $F$ is either nonsense or needs more information to define it on $x<0$.

Comment: It is easier to show that the derivative of $f$ is bounded for in this case, it is Lipschitz and so AC.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x > 0$. Then,

$$ \int_0^x F'(t) \, dt = \int_0^\varepsilon F'(t) \, dt + \int_\varepsilon^x F'(t) \, dt $$

Since we can apply FTC on $[\varepsilon, 1]$, the right-hand side is equal to

$$ \int_0^\varepsilon F'(t) \, dt + F(x) - F(\varepsilon) $$

Because $F'$ is integrable, the integral in the middle tends to $0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. Also, $F(\varepsilon)$ tends to $F(0)$. Hence, in the limit you get $F(x) - F(0)$.

Edit: I didn't pay attention to the fact that $x^{-5/4}$ is not defined for negative values of $x$. You should consider $F$ only on $[0, 1]$. I changed my proof accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean that $F(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ ($x\ne 0$), $F(0)=0$ also has FTC on $[-1,1]$? The fact that $F'\notin L^1([-1,1])$ is what makes it not AC?

Comment: @trex Why do you say $x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ also has FTC? This proof cannot apply to it, because $F'$ is not integrable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It makes sense now.

Comment: I see. Maybe I should have used $x^{-6/5}$!